# Fisheye: Make fisheye as a service

Tags: service, atlassian-fisheye

I'm working on making fisheye work as a service, I folowed this link:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/how-to-start-fisheye-and-crucible-at-boot-time-223216848.html
I change the **$FISHEYE_HOME** that contains **fisheyectl.sh**
But when running th service i got this:

> fisheye systemd[1]: Stopped fisheye.service.
>   fisheye systemd[1]:
>   Starting fisheye.service...
>   fisheye fisheye[3788]: **No passwd
>   entry for user 'fisheye'**
>   fisheye systemd[1]: Started
>   fisheye.service.

The service is not ruunig now and i don't know why ?
Any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a solution for this , simply I created a user "fisheye" then I execute the command

```
  chown -R fisheye:fisheye /home/user/Downloads/fisheye
  chown -R fisheye:fisheye /home/user/fisheye
```

I hope that can help anyone who face this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more comprehensive guide on this here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/how-to-create-a-service-for-fisheye-crucible-in-linux-1041080637.html

Within that documentation there is a link to https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/installing-fisheye-on-linux-and-mac-960155263.html which mentions:

> [User running Fisheye] be a non-privileged user with read, write and
> execute access on the Fisheye install directory and instance (data)
> directory.

This is why changing the ownership recursively of those directories to be that of the fisheye user worked.